# How to access implicit "=" function for an array type when it is overloaded in the same package?

Tags: vhdl

I had a sudden thought. Is it possible to access the implicit "=" function for an array type when an overload exists in the same package as the array type declaration?

For example, in `numeric_std`, the `unsigned` and `signed` types are declared, along with overloads for the `"="` function.

Lets say I want to compare an exact bitstring for signed and unsigned types, for example:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;  -- added to make full path to "=" function a requirement

variable a, b : unsigned(7 downto 0);
...
a := "UXUXUXUX";
b := "UXUXUXUX";

if a = b then  -- this fails with the overloaded "=" function
```

If I could access the implicit "=" function for unsigned, then the `a = b` check would pass. but `ieee.numeric_std."="` will go direct to the overloaded version.

The only workaround here is to convert to `std_logic_vector` and compare using the implicit "=" function in std_logic_1164:

```
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;
use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;  -- added to make full path to "=" function a requirement

variable a, b : unsigned(7 downto 0);
...
a := "UXUXUXUX";
b := "UXUXUXUX";

if ieee.std_logic_1164."="(std_logic_vector(a), std_logic_vector(b) ) then
```

Unless I am missing a way to get at the implicit "=" function for unsigned?

Comment: Your *sudden thought* should be practicable, a [mcve] demonstrating need. numeric_std_unsigned is -2008, along with numeric_std a *synthesis package*. 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values "The values 'U', 'X', 'W', and '–' are metalogical values; they define the behavior of the model itself rather than the behavior of the hardware being synthesized. The value 'U' represents the value of an object before it is explicitly assigned a value during simulation; the values 'X' and 'W' represent forcing and weak values, respectively, for which the model is not able to distinguish between logic levels."

Comment: 16.8.2.4.4 Metalogical values in relational expressions "If the VHDL source code includes an equality operator (=) for which one operand is a static metalogical value and for which the other operand is not a static value, a synthesis tool shall interpret the equality relation as equivalent to the BOOLEAN value FALSE., If one operand of an equality relation is a one- dimensional array, and one element of that one-dimensional array is a static metalogical value, a synthesis tool shall interpret the entire equality relation as equivalent to the BOOLEAN value FALSE."

Comment: Your last code snippet isn't valid syntax. An operator symbol designator (4.2 Subprogram declarations) can't be a selected name. Overcome with a [function call](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kL6Z1.jpg). Overload operators are implemented in function definitions (4.5.2 Operator overloading).

Comment: For flow control in simulation there are places where the original equality operator are guaranteed to be used. Case statement choices and case expressions, selected signal assignments (which have an equivalent case statement), case generate statements and detecting changes in signal updates (for events). The bit about case generate statements can lead to the idea of using instantiated external blocks (entities) to control visibility. Likewise overloading locally with a use clause to insure the "=" operator of choice is used.

Answer (score 0):

Why not write your own function and call it with function call syntax rather than operator syntax?   The similar problem I ran into is with `?=` / STD_MATCH.   In the OSVVM package AlertLogPkg, I created MetaMatch.   It is similar to STD_MATCH, except it returns TRUE for U=U, X=X, Z=Z, and W=W.   All other values are consistent with STD_MATCH.

```vhdl
  type BooleanTableType is array(std_ulogic, std_ulogic) of boolean;

  constant MetaMatchTable : BooleanTableType := (
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    -- U      X      0      1      Z      W      L      H      -
    --------------------------------------------------------------------------
    (TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),  -- | U |
    (FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),  -- | X |
    (FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE),  -- | 0 |
    (FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),  -- | 1 |
    (FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),  -- | Z |
    (FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, TRUE),  -- | W |
    (FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, TRUE),  -- | L |
    (FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE,  TRUE),  -- | H |
    (TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE,  TRUE)   -- | - |
    );

  function MetaMatch (l, r : std_ulogic) return boolean is
  begin
    return MetaMatchTable(l, r);
  end function MetaMatch;

  function MetaMatch (L, R : std_ulogic_vector) return boolean is
    alias aL : std_ulogic_vector(1 to L'length) is L;
    alias aR : std_ulogic_vector(1 to R'length) is R;
  begin
    if aL'length /= aR'length then
      --! log(OSVVM_ALERTLOG_ID, "AlertLogPkg.MetaMatch: Length Mismatch", DEBUG) ;
      return FALSE;
    else
      for i in aL'range loop
        if not (MetaMatchTable(aL(i), aR(i))) then
          return FALSE;
        end if;
      end loop;
      return TRUE;
    end if;
  end function MetaMatch;
```

Comment: There's also a non-object alias in an inner declarative region which could be wrapped in a function: `function "=" (l,r: std_logic_vector) return boolean is alias "=" is ieee.std_logic_1164."=" [std_ulogic_vector, std_ulogic_vector return boolean] begin return l = r;  end function;` Without a specific programming problem supplying limitations the OP's readers would be speculating on what's needed. (Nice subtle advert for OSVVM though.)

Comment: So the answer is, its not possible. You need to define one?

Comment: Under what constraints Tricky? 16.8.5 Packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values, 16.8.5.1 General "Four VHDL packages for arithmetic using bit and standard logic values are defined by this standard. The NUMERIC_BIT and NUMERIC_BIT_UNSIGNED packages are based on the VHDL type BIT, while the NUMERIC_STD and NUMERIC_STD_UNSIGNED packages are based on the type STD_ULOGIC. ... "***The four packages are mutually incompatible, and only one shall be used in any given design unit***." Stick to numeric_std. (This semantic rule hasn't been enforced, perhaps it should be.)

Comment: @Tricky In the case of numeric_std, the explicit declaration hides the implicit one and they are both in the same declarative region, so I don't think there is a way.